# How to Add All Songs of Apple Music Playlist to My Music at Once?

Tags: itunes, playlist, apple-music

When browsing through Apple Music, there are curated Apple Music Playlists.

Now, I can add each song of the Apple Music Playlist to "My Music" by right clicking and selecting "Add to my Music". That's very inconvenient, when I want to add all songs of that playlist to "My Music".

Is there any easier way? Any one-click solution?

Comment: Please post an answer below instead of adding it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

Here are the steps to force iTunes to add all songs of an Apple Music Playlist to your local iTunes “My Music” library:

1. Add the Apple Music Playlist to your library by clicking on the + icon on the upper right.
2. Go to the Playlists tab and select the recently added Apple Music Playlist. Now select all tracks and right click on any of them to select “New Playlist from Selection”.
3. After iTunes has created a new playlist, go back to the original one to select all tracks again and drag them over to your new playlists. Skip adding duplicates.
4. You’re done - now all these tracks should be added to your local iTunes “My Music” libray and you can safely delete both playlists!

Easier option (from iMac):

1. Add the Apple Music Playlist to your library by clicking on the + icon on the upper right.
2. Now that this new playlist appears in your left tab with all your playlists, drag it to your other playlist

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Apparently, this is still how it works five years later...

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, on both iTunes and your Apple device. You didn't mention which device specifically, but on iTunes, look for the `+` icon or the `...`, which you can click and `Add to My Music` as well.

Check out these screenshots below on iTunes. I boxed the + icon on both pictures because that is the simpler approach, but you can also click the `...`:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hm, yes... But it doesn't do what it should, i think! If I click on "Add to My Music", wait for a bit. Then click on it again, to make sure the entry "Add to My Music" isn't showing up anymore. Then go back to "My Music" and search for a track, e.g. Drake - Legend. It does not show up... Shouldn't it?

Comment: Ah yes. Well in perfect circumstances this does work. But what you're facing is what many users are facing too. Apple Music, which relies on icloud music library, is very buggy, and changes you make to your library don't work automatically. I've faced this issue with rating songs. There isn't a fix for this really yet, but you can try restarting, signing out, etc

Comment: Ok cool, thx for clarifying/veryfing that ;) Yeah iCloud/iTunes Match has been buggy for years now. I am really surprised it's such a disaster ...

Comment: Finally found a solution, I've described it on my blog: https://blog.benmarten.me/2015/12/24/How-to-Add-all-Songs-of-a-Apple-Music-Playlist-to-My-Music-Library/

Answer (score 2):

2021, iTunes got replaced by **Music**.

1. Add playlist any way you do it (I migrated from another streaming platform)
2. Open **Music** and go to this playlist. Make sure it's open in **Music** - songs get 100% of playlist window
3. `Command + A` -> `Add to Library`

Answer (score 0):

The + sign is no longer in apple music on playlists I have created. I found a different solution on my own by opening Apple Music on my laptop, clicking file in the top left corner, clicking Add to library, then selecting my Music Folder on the side bar, then clicking the desired playlist, and finally, selecting all the songs in the playlist and clicking Open. To get the same thing to happen on your phone, follow these steps while your phone is connected to your computer through USB. Then (on your computer), go to recently added on your apple music library sidebar, and highlight every album. Right click one of the albums and click "add to my music". Your playlist should be successfully imported into your library!